# Нахождение значения в определенной точке (внутри) треугольника

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия, интерполяция

К примеру у меня есть треугольник с вершинами `A` `B` `C`. Каждая из этих вершин ассоциирована с некоторым значением (абстрагируемся от типа этого значения - главное, что он подвержен линейной интерполяции): `x`, `y`, `z` - для каждой из вершин соответственно. Также есть некоторая точка `D` лежащая внутри треугольника или на одной стороне треугольника. Как максимально просто (за меньшее количество действий) найти значение в точке `D`?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: Определяете барицентрические координаты, и берёте средневзвешенное значений в вершинах с коэффициентами, равными координатам

Comment: а не сводится ли это к билинейной интерполяции? правда вычислений там явно будет больше чем в случае с барицентрическими координатами..

Comment: Очень не точно задача сформулирована. Что значит "вершинам ассоциировано значение" ?? Это значение должно быть одно из {x, y, z} - и обычно это z. Имея {x, y} его и нужно находить - это как линейная интерполяция расширенная на двумерный случай

Comment: @StrangerintheQ как мне кажется это свелось бы к билинейной интерполяции если бы было 4 точки образующие прямоугольник, а тут всего 3 точки

Comment: @ampawd 4 найти линейной по ребрам, я попробую и расскажу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Уравнение плоскости через 3 точки - `Ax+By+С=z` (в таком виде, чтоб легче считать), получаем отсюда A,B,C из решения системы трех уравнений

```
A*x1+B*y1+C == z1
A*x2+B*y2+C == z2
A*x3+B*y3+C == z3
```

Ну, а потом просто подставляем `x,y` и получаем...

Если не ошибся в расчетах -

```
double tri(double x, double y,
           double x1, double y1, double z1,
           double x2, double y2, double z2,
           double x3, double y3, double z3)
{
    double q = (x2-x3)*y1 - (x1-x3)*y2 + (x1-x2)*y3;
    double A = (y3-y2)*z1 + (y1-y3)*z2 - (y1-y2)*z3;
    double B = (x2-x3)*z1 + (x3-x1)*z2 + (x1-x2)*z3;
    double C = (x3*y2-x2*y3)*z1 - (x3*y1-x1*y3)*z2 + (x2*y1-x1*y2)*z3;

    return (A*x+B*y+C)/q;
}
```

Само собой, если расчетов много - то можно рассчитать `A,B,C,q` один раз и считать значения для разных точек...

Если `q==0` - дело плохо, три точки на одной прямой...

Для конкретно сторон (точек на сторонах) можно упростить - там третья точка не нужна, просто записать уравнение прямой достаточно.